# ¿Cuando debo usar async/await y cuando no?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asincronismo

Estoy trabajando con Entity Framework con ASP MVC y tengo la siguiente duda, ¿Siempre debo usar los métodos asíncronos? o en que debería basarme para optar entre uno y otro?

**Asíncrono**

```
private static async Task AddStudent()
{
   Student myStudent = new Student();
   using (var context = new SchoolDBEntities())
   {           
      context.Students.Add(myStudent);
      await context.SaveChangesAsync();           
   }
}
```

**Síncrono**

```
private static void AddStudent()
{
   Student myStudent = new Student();
   using (var context = new SchoolDBEntities())
   {           
      context.Students.Add(myStudent);
      context.SaveChanges();           
   }
}
```

Comment: échale un ojo a este post https://geeks.ms/etomas/2011/09/17/c-5-async-await/

Comment: @HectorLopez muchísimas gracias por el articulo, es simplemente espectacular la explicación

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Debes usar *async/await* cuando tengas una tarea que tome tiempo considerable y debas esperar a que termine. Por lo general son procesos que involucran operaciones de Entrada/Salida y el compilador genera una máquina de estado finito al invocarlos. Si tu programa no necesita esperar por el resultado de una operacion compleja, entonces puedes utilizar un enfoque tradicional síncrono ya que éste se ejecutará independientemente.

En tu ejemplo si al guardar la información del estudiante deseas mostrar esos cambios de forma inmediata debes usar el enfoque asíncrono, de otro modo no sabras si el objeto estudiante se ha guardado o no en disco ya que es difícil saber si la operación de escritura se ejecutará inmediatamente, obteniendo información no actualizada en la siguiente carga de datos. Si por el contrario no te importa mostrar/usar los datos inmediatamente luego de invocar el método guardar puedes utilizar indudablemente el método síncrono. Esto hace que se lance un proceso separado por cada tarea que no sea inmediata, sin bloquear la ejecución en el bloque de código.

Para hacerlo entender mejor escribimos el siguiente ejemplo:

```
public async Task MetodoAsincronoPrincipal()
{
    // aqui hacemos los cambios al objeto student
    Task<int> tareaLarga= SaveChangesAsync();
    // El código independiente de la tarea se escribe aqui

    // ahora esperamos el resultado
    int result = await tareaLarga;
    // tenemos el resultado y lo podemos utilizar en este punto
}

public async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync() // Retornamos un entero como ejemplo 
{
    await Task.Delay(1000); // 1 segundo de retardo
    return 1;
}
```

Ahora explicamos:

*Task  tareaLarga = SaveChangesAsync()* se ejecuta independientemente en un hilo separado. El código ejecutado a partir de esta linea se sigue ejecutando normalmente en el hilo principal y puede tomar todo el tiempo que necesite. Luego en la linea  *int result = await tareaLarga;* El hilo principal espera por el hilo creado con *SaveChangesAsync* para seguir la ejecución normalmente.  En el caso de que el código independiente de la tarea principal tarde mas de 1 segundo, el metodo *SaveChangesAsync* devolvera 1 directamente ya que el código se ha ejecutado en un hilo independiente manteniendo el estado.